# How to make webpack compile in ES6?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have Webpack 2.x. By default this compiles the code in ES5. How to change it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, you are supposed to have a loader for your webpack compiled files. You can take a look at the babel-loader. Include it in your webpack config, and you should be able to configure it to transpile to ES6.

Comment: Can you show any example of config for the loader for ES6?

Comment: Just I use a built-in config in Laravel Elixir but I can extend it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [babel preset env](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-env) to target the browsers and not include IE in the list and probably the specific versions of browsers you are using. That should transpile only to latest versions. Otherwise you can specify specific presets that you want to transpile in the babelrc file to only transpile those.